# Making a flashing image

Tags: python, kivy

I've been trying to make a flashing picture in kivy but since loops and time.sleep() can't be used in kivy, I don't know how to deal with it.

- python 3
- kivy 1.11.0

I've looked for similar projects and samples but I couldn't find any. I've found some code about a flashing text (like one below), but it gives an error. (btw due to some limitations, I can't use the .kv format.)

```
anim  = Animation(alpha=0, duration=0.1) + Animation(alpha=0, duration=1)
anim += Animation(alpha=1, duration=0.1) + Animation(alpha=1, duration=1)
anim.repeat = True
anim.start(widget)
```

the error that I get:

```
original_value = getattr(widget, key)
 AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'alpha'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Image`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html) does not have the alpha property so you get that error, if you want to modify the alpha you must use the [`color`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.color) property.

```py
anim = Animation(color=[1, 1, 1, 0], duration=0.1)
anim += Animation(color=[1, 1, 1, 0], duration=1)
anim += Animation(color=[1, 1, 1, 1], duration=0.1)
anim += Animation(color=[1, 1, 1, 1], duration=1)
anim.repeat = True
anim.start(widget)
```

Comment: @BehradX I recommend you check the docs, there you will find precise information that the projects do not indicate.